# how to set Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) in settings visual studio in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, configuration, app-config, appsettings

I tried to create desktop settings path in Visual Studio but it doesn't work
is there any other solution?

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & \Google Drive
```

[image: settings]

Comment: That's not an information you store in Settings, it's something you read, at run-time, each time you need it, right before you use it

Comment: @Jimi , how can I create a desktop path in settings so that it can be used between other computers

Comment: @dbasnett , if I use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` it without in the settings and can I use it for different each computer so why can't I use it in settings

Comment: @And - The desktop path is different for each computer hence the call to Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop). What are you trying to accomplish by this?

Comment: @dbasnett , if I use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) it without in the settings and can I use it for different each computer so why can't I use it in settings

Comment: @And - Jimi explained why you can't put that statement in settings.  **What are you trying to do?**

Comment: @dbasnett , `Jimi explained why you can't put that statement in settings. What are you trying to do?` I tried to in the settings so that it made it easier to change the path in the config file according to what I wanted. But the problem is that I didn't succeed

Comment: @And - I've shown an answer that might help.  **What config file?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the Shown event, assuming this is a Forms app.

```
Private GoogleDrive As String
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    GoogleDrive = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "GoogleDrive")
    'now just use the variable GoogleDrive
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and whether I can "googledrive" I located it in the settings so that it becomes exe.config